# app.UseCookieAuthentication does not seem to be working for cookiename or expiretimespan

Tags: asp.net-identity

In asp.net 5 + (asp.net identity 3.0) I am trying to rename the cookie and see if I can set the log out value from its default.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      app.UseIdentity();

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {

                CookieName = "MyCookie",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0),

            });
}
```

[image]

The cookie name is not being renamed to MyCookie and     ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0) is not "logging me out after 1 minute) or setting the . I do get redirected to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you have to use

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(
                   options => {

                       options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme = "MyCookie";
                       options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = IdentityCookieOptions.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationType = "MyCookie";
                       options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
                       options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "MyCookie";


                   })
```

}

I was using IApplicationBuilder app

```
  app.UseIdentity().UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
```

... ect

So basically using IServiceCollection AddIdentity fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines inside your `CookieAuthenticationOptions`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
{
    CookieName = "MyCookie", 
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0), 
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider 
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0),
            (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, user))
    }
});
```

As I can see in Identity 2.0 configuration is the same as in 3.0 and these is a working example. You need to provide to `Identity` provider settings

Comment: I don't see a provider option anywhere.

Comment: Its the property in `CookieAuthenticationOptions` class. I updated my answer